# Write an ansible script

Tags: ansible

How do you push an rpm from a server to 100 different servers using an ansible script?

source location:`/home/jsachin/tsi/`
destination location on 100 servers: `/home/jsachin/tsi/`

Comment: what have you tried, start by trying something and when that does not work then post what you did and how it is not working so we can help

Comment: The copy or synchronize module would be a good place to start looking

Answer (score 1):

Using the copy module should do this for you:

```
- name: Copy file to server
  copy: src="{{ source_file }}" dest="{{ dest_file }}"
```

Where `source_file` refers to the full path to the file on your Ansible server, and `dest_file` refers to the full path and file name to save it as on the server Ansible is working on.

Comment: Question here is to push the rpm on 100 servers how can we put that in the copy script?

Comment: @Joe The list of "100 servers" is just the list that you provide to Ansible to run the script against.  It's the same way you run any Ansible script against a specific set of servers.